# (React-Navigation) Called redux action many times on when screen loading

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

Hi when I enter screen with TabNavigator (have 5 tabs) and one of them is calling redux action on componentWillMount. But the weird things is why it never stop calling the action.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code for the action along with the code where it is called?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you are calling `setState` from inside a lifecycle method. It sets off a chain reaction because the component re-renders when Redux updates, and re-rendering causes Redux to update.

I would imagine this is the source of your problem.

To fix it, you will need to improve how it is setting the state, such as updating only the field that is needed, or making the component only listen to that one field, or not updating it there.

You could also add conditionals, such as `if (this && this) dont update`

Also very good to investigate is `if (props === nextProps) dont update`

You might need to look at `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method, but I would say generally, that should be avoided because it can create strange bugs that are hard to track down.